# I would like to set my date from a range of dates, and then loop through the list of dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set the sDate variable in my code to come from a list of date in a range.

My code works for one date, but for the life of me I can't remember how to loop through a list of dates.

When I have one in the cell called "BusinessDate", it works...

```
Public Function sGetDate () as Date
Dim DateRng as Range
Dim sDate as Date
Set DateRng = Sheets("Control").Range("BusinessDate")
```

I thought I could do something like this for a loop of 10 dates from a list:

```
Public Function sGetDate () as Date
Dim DateRng as Range
Dim sDate as Date
Set DateRng = Sheets("Control").Range("BusinessDateList")

If i = 1 To 10
sDate = BusinessDateList(i)
Next i
End If

Once the date is set from the list, it can loop through the existing code.

This doesn't seem to work at setting the date, but I it's been so long since I have looked at any vba I can't think of where to start.  Any help would be great.
```

Comment: And what should be the `return` ? Because of now you would just loop through dates without doing anything. When should the loop stop?

Comment: You have `**If** i = 1 To 10`.  Change it to `**For** i = 1 To 10`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks - of course it should be FOR!  Thank you for your help.  I've been staring at this for way too long.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the For Each

e.g.

```
Each c in DateRng
debug.print c.value
next
```